# I'm trying to practice variable length argument codes.this is my first code

Tags: python-3.x

getting the out put 25.

```python
def myFun(*n):
    for x in n:
        return x*x

print(myFun(5,2,5))
```

expected results

```
 25
 4
 25
```

Comment: You need to use `def myFun(*n):` if you want a variable amount of arguments.

Comment: Change `return x*x` to `yield x*x` and use for-loop for print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `return`, the execution stops, you should use `yield` instead.

```
def myFun(*n):
    for x in n:
        yield x*x

for i in  myFun(5, 2, 5):
    print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
25 
4 
25
```